# What are these objects or nodes called in JavaScript when making a web based visualizer?

Tags: javascript, html, json, object, nodes

I'm setting up a road map for a project I'm working on and i cant seem to find any information on how to create a object in JavaScript that is a block of information with three or more fields.

I am taking the information from a JSON file. The problem is that i don't know what to look for, I don't know the name for this type of object/node. When i search for "JavaScript node" the only thing that comes up is nodejs.

The object/node is supposed to be shown in a browser and should look something like the picture. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAZ38.png

```
{ "class": "go.TreeModel",
  "nodeDataArray": [
{"id":1337, "name":"Project number one", "title": "node"},
{"id":7335, "name":"Project number two", "title": "node"},
{"id":13337, "name":"Project child 1", "title": "node", "parent":1337},
{"id":72616, "name":"Project child 9", "title": "node", "parent":7335},
{"id":72612, "name":"Project child 10", "title": "node", "parent":7335},
 ]
}
```

The end idea is for it to work where i can view all the projects and see what parents they come from.

The first problem I'm trying to solve is just understanding how I should visualize two blocks in a browser window.
A requirement is that I can build new features easily and add how many nodes/objects as i wish.

Comment: you may need a charting library to connect the blocks

Comment: There are two questions here - one on terminology and one on implementation.  It would probably be clearer if you just ask one of them.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're trying to program in HTML/JS/CSS a way to create visualizations of your `nodateDataArray` objects, and their relationships to their parents?

Comment: @brk So I need to use some sort of library? The thing was that I want to do my own sorting on them with my own algorithm. But if i need a library, what library would you recommend?

Comment: Correct, something along those lines @TKoL

Comment: @EuanSmith The terminology is based on how i try to implement it i asume.

Comment: @Luddeb123 you need to have a basic html/css/js knowledge to begin a project like that. Based on the vagueness of your question, it seems to me like you don't have that yet.

Comment: @Luddeb123 I had read this, possibly mistakenly, that your question was about 1. js terminology and 2. how to visualise.  JS terminology is, by design, light.  Objects have properties, and the values of those properties can be other objects.  There is no schema and little formal structure.  (For example an array looks just like any other JS object, it just has properties of '0', '1', etc plus a 'length'.  However you are free to add any others).  I'm not sure if there is a library to do exactly what you want.  d3.js could do it, but if you don't have much js experience that would be tough.